# Templating systems for Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, templates, symfony1

I've recently started to learn symfony framework and I wonder what are the best choices for a templating system?

Some suggest to just use PHP but I don't really like that (btw, see this [interesting article](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/34/templating-engines-in-php)).

Before I started with symfony, I used - and liked - Smarty.

Are there better options for symfony?

Comment: What is it about plain PHP that you don't like?

Comment: @yitznewton, I actually agree with many things in that link I posted. PHP is missing some cool things and is a bit too wordy for a template system - that makes the templates hard to read, even with syntax highlighting. I used to use PHP for templates some years ago, then switched to Smarty and never regretted it.

Comment: fair enough - as long as you've thought it out :) Did you try http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfSmarty3Plugin

Comment: Yeah I've tried it but couldn't get it to work... I'll just wait for symfony2 (see below). Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [Twig](http://www.twig-project.org/) (developed by Sensio/Fabien Potencier)... there is a [plugin for symfony 1.4](https://github.com/henrikbjorn/sfTwigPlugin), and it will be the default templating bundle in Symfony2

Comment: @prodigitalson: Ah, I've disregarded Twig when I couldn't find any plugin for symfony 1.4 in their plugin database. I'll take a look at it!

Comment: @Czech: While you may find some engines with plugins for 1.4 if i were you i would just assume youre going to have to wire it up yourself...

Comment: Well if you dont have a pressing project that might be best. OTOH, if youre jsut learning 1.4 then you would be better off jsut using PHP templating until you are comfortable with it.. because anytime you have a problem its always going to have the question of "is it an issue with the templating"

Comment: @prodigitalson, project is not pressing so instead I'm diving in the symfony2 documentation and waiting for the v2 to come out, hopefully with [jobeet](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/) v2! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you liked Smarty and want to use it in **Symfony2** this is possible by adding [SmartyBundle](https://github.com/noiselabs/SmartyBundle). Check out the [documentation](https://github.com/noiselabs/SmartyBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst) for installation and usage details.

Comment: +1 for the info, thanks! But now I'm already fully in the process of converting my templates to Twig. It misses some things of Smarty but has other useful features that Smarty doesn't support. In the end, it's just a matter of habit.